# No route found for "GET /demo/koco/create" : 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: symfony, routes

Why I am getting errors for the route?
Other APIs for the CRUD operation are working fine.
I have added a new controller code for my new API and I am getting a route error.
What could be the mistake?

While I have already written my route in **routing.yml**

```
creat:
  path: /create
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController:create }
  methods: [GET]

Products:
  path: /recentProducts/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController:recentProducts }
  methods: [GET]

Update:
  path: /updateProduct/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController:update }
  methods: [POST]

Delete:
  path: /deleteProduct/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController:delete }
  methods: [DELETE]

referenceCreation:
  path: /koco/create
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:DemoController:createReference }
  methods: [GET]
```

**My api is**
`http://localhost/koco1/web/app_dev.php/demo/koco/create`

**My Controller is**

```
/**
     * @Route("/koco/create", name="referenceCreation")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function createReferenceAction()
    {

        $organization = new Organization();
        $organization->setName('Sensio Lab');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setName("Jonathan H. Wage");
        $user->setOrganization($organization);


        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $dm->persist($organization);
        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush();

        return new Response('Created product id ');

        // $response = new Response('Hello Huzaifa ');
        // return $response;
    }
```

What is wrong here?
Kindly let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Use `bin/console debug:router` to show your configured routes.  Probably offer a clue.  And mixing annotations with a routing.yaml can technically work but can become confusing to maintain.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used the router:debug command and identified that my URL was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing is off.
Also you are creating routes through yaml and through annotations. Should stick to one.

Also server setup looks off too, http://localhost/koco1/web/app_dev.php/demo/koco/create should be more like http://localhost/koco1/web/koco/create, you can try running php server. Going to /public and running php -S localhost:8000 you can read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

or symfony cli server https://symfony.com/download

Your routes does not match /demo/koco/create is not equal to /koco/create, you should first of all set up correctly, then it will be easier to debug.

Comment: You are right. /demo/koco/create is different from /koco/create. I realized that and the problem was resolved. Many thanks